# is there any grid component which supports right to left layout in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, grid

I was wondering if there is a grid like devextra grid (or like tadvancedgrid in delphi) which supports right to left layout completely

i want some data grid which i can set more properties than dataGridView on it

to set skins , data formats for each column ,data navigation tools , background image for grid

column grouping tools filtering tools , printing tools , ....

(something which has more flexibility than DataGridView)

Comment: don't introduce me datagridview please

Comment: Specifically, what "more flexibility" are you talking about? What's wrong with the `DataGridView`? I've seen a couple of questions recently like this; you can't just assume that we can read your mind.

Comment: @Cody Gray:sry my friend

Comment: I don't know what the `EmbeddedNavigator` or `LookAndFeel` properties do, either. I was hoping for an actual *description* of the requirements, not just a list of properties. The developer can name properties anything (s)he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [`DataGridView` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) is the one most commonly used.

More detailed information is available in [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsarabic/archive/2009/01/29/datagridview-with-rtl-columns.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[`DataGridView` has property `RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)

Pretty much every standard control in Windows Forms support [`RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx).

Not sure what you want to achieve, but it probably makes more sense to set `RightToLeft` in the form. It will be automatically propagated to the child controls, instead of setting this property for every single control.

Comment: :yea but i want something like devexpress components. and they doesn't support RightToLeftLayout. thanx

Answer (score 0):

There is a RightToLeftLayout property actually, but it is not implemented everywhere, besides:

> Unlike RightToLeft, RightToLeftLayout
>   does not inherit. If you want it to
>   take effect for child controls, you
>   must set it on each child control that
>   you want mirrored. (from MSDN)

some details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsarabic/archive/2010/02/18/what-is-righttoleftlayout.aspx)

For the DataGridView you can use RightToLeft

Comment: :yea but i want something like devexpress components. and they doesn't support RightToLeftLayout.  thanx