# Is there any grid like tadvgrid of delphi in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

Is there any grid like tadvgrid of delphi in c# ?(which supports right to left completely)

There are several grid components for `desktop application` development like `xtragrid` but they doesn't support `rtl`.

any suggestion?
thanks in advance

Comment: [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079790/is-there-any-grid-component-which-supports-right-to-left-layout-in-visual-studio)?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize DataGridView, it is DataAware and you can customize its rendering
It is also RTL compatible

Comment: thanx but i want some grid like xtragrid

Answer (score 0):

If you do ASP.Net using MVC you can use Telerik  MVC Grid as Free. Take a look on Demo. 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid

Comment: :thanx amir but as i've written i want it for desktop app